Expression manipulations on similar expressions give different simplified expressions
Start with this list of two expressions :
foo = {(bet2*bet3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]^3 + bet2*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]^3 - 
   alp3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - bet3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*
    Subscript[ep, 2] - bet2*bet3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - 
   Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - 
   bet2*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - 
   alp1*bet2*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
   alp3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
   alp1*alp3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
   bet3*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
   Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
   alp1*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
   alp1*bet2*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 - 
   alp1*alp3*l3*Subscript[ep, 2]^3 - alp1*Subscript[b, 3]*
    Subscript[ep, 2]^3 + bet2*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   alp1*bet2*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   bet2*Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   bet2*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   alp1*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   bet2*l3*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   alp1*bet2*Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*
    Subscript[ep, 3] - Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*
    Subscript[ep, 3] - alp1*bet2*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]*
    Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] - alp1*l3*Subscript[ep, 2]^2*
    Subscript[ep, 3] + alp1*bet2*l3*Subscript[ep, 2]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   alp1*Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   alp1*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 2]^2*Subscript[ep, 3])/
  ((Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*(bet2*Subscript[ep, 1] - 
    Subscript[ep, 2])*(Subscript[ep, 1] - alp1*Subscript[ep, 2])), 
 (alp2*alp3*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]^3 + alp3*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]^3 + 
   alp3*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - 
   alp3*bet1*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - 
   alp3*Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
   alp3*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 2] - 
   alp2*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   alp2*alp3*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   bet2*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   alp3*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   alp3*bet1*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]^2*Subscript[ep, 3] - 
   alp3*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   bet1*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
   alp3*bet1*Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*
    Subscript[ep, 3] - Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*
    Subscript[ep, 3] - alp3*bet1*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 1]*
    Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + alp2*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]*
    Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + bet2*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + 
   bet1*bet2*l2*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + 
   Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + 
   bet1*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + 
   alp3*bet1*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 - 
   bet1*l2*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + 
   alp3*bet1*l2*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 - 
   bet1*Subscript[b, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 + 
   bet1*Subscript[b, 3]*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]^2 - 
   bet1*bet2*l2*Subscript[ep, 3]^3 - bet1*Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]^3)/
  ((Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 3])*(alp3*Subscript[ep, 1] - 
    Subscript[ep, 3])*(Subscript[ep, 1] - bet1*Subscript[ep, 3]))}

Then simplify each of the component :
Simplify/@foo
While the second component is simplified to
S2=bet2*l2 + Subscript[b, 2] + ((Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 2])/
   (-Subscript[ep, 1] + Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
  (alp3*l2*(bet2*Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2]))/
   (-(alp3*Subscript[ep, 1]) + Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
  (l2*(alp2*Subscript[ep, 1] - bet1*Subscript[ep, 2]))/
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - bet1*Subscript[ep, 3])

the first has more complicated expression :
NS1=(bet2*(bet3*l3 + Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]^3 + 
   Subscript[ep, 1]^2*(-(((alp3 + bet3 + bet2*bet3)*l3 + 
        (1 + bet2 + alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 2]) + 
     bet2*(l3 - alp1*l3 - Subscript[b, 1] + Subscript[b, 2])*
      Subscript[ep, 3]) + alp1*Subscript[ep, 2]^2*
    (-((alp3*l3 + Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 2]) + 
     ((-1 + bet2)*l3 - Subscript[b, 1] + Subscript[b, 2])*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
   Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*
    (((alp3 + alp1*alp3 + bet3)*l3 + (1 + alp1 + alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
      Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*l3 - bet2*l3 + Subscript[b, 1] + 
       alp1*bet2*Subscript[b, 1] - (1 + alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 2])*
      Subscript[ep, 3]))/((Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*
   (bet2*Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*(Subscript[ep, 1] - 
    alp1*Subscript[ep, 2]))

However I know that from symmetry property the two components "should behave" the same. Indeed, we can check by hand that the first component is :
S1=bet3*l3 + Subscript[b, 3] + ((Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[b, 2])*
   Subscript[ep, 3])/(-Subscript[ep, 1] + Subscript[ep, 2]) + 
 l3*((alp1*bet3*Subscript[ep, 2] - alp1*Subscript[ep, 3])/
    (Subscript[ep, 1] - alp1*Subscript[ep, 2]) - 
   (alp3*Subscript[ep, 2] - bet2*Subscript[ep, 3])/
    (bet2*Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2]))

which looks like the simplified second component S2.

My question is how to get the simplified first component S1 using mathematica instructions : I tried to apply typical functions to NS1 like Expand, Apart, FullSimplify ... but mathematica kept returning the non simplied expression NS1.
Moreover we would expect that Mathematica gives directly the expression S1 using only the Simplify like it did for S2 but it doesn't. Why is that ? Because seeing the expressions of S1 and S2 they have common patterns.
I would not characterize it as a bug because I do believe I must not use properly Mathematica to manipulate such expressions, and I expect from this topic to give me insights on how Simplify work and why it seems it is working "stochastically".
I am using Mathematica 14.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Use Apart[expr,var]
Apart[#, Subscript[ep, 1]] & /@ foo


